# IndexOutOfRange when player reaches maxLevel

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm having difficulties with this code, getting an IndexOutOfRange error everytime the player hits maxLevel. 
After hitting maxLevel, currentEXP will reset to 0, only after hitting 'K' again.

[image: Unity Inspector View]

Could it be that I'm missing another if-statement. Maybe inside the while-loop? Encasing the while-loop? What condition would it have?

```
 // Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    expToNextLevel = new int[maxLevel];
    expToNextLevel[1] = baseEXP;

    for (int i = 2; i < expToNextLevel.Length; i++)
    {
        expToNextLevel[i] = Mathf.FloorToInt(expToNextLevel[i - 1] * 1.3f);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
    {
        AddExp(100);
    }
}

//Adds EXP and levels up the character
public void AddExp(int expToAdd)
{
    currentEXP += expToAdd;

    //performs functions as long as playerLevel doesn't exceed maxLevel
    if (playerLevel < maxLevel)
    {
        //level up to the equivalent level with all the exp gain up to that level
        while (currentEXP > expToNextLevel[playerLevel])
        {
                currentEXP -= expToNextLevel[playerLevel];
                playerLevel++;
        }

    } else {
        currentEXP = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use Length property instead of a pre-set max level since that may be why. And just a reminder but arrays start with 0 index not 1 so length 100 means it starts with lvl0 and ends with lvl99. Thats why I suppose.

Comment: Likely adding `playerLevel < maxLevel` to the while loop would work as I assume expToNextLevel only indexes up to maxLevel - 1.  You'd also need to check when the player level has maxed out after the while loop so you'll reset `currentEXP`.

Comment: @lv Misticos I've added the code, which handles the array. The size of the array is determined by the defined maxLevel. The needed experience to achieve a level, should start at index 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking if the player is max level, just run the code to level the character up until the player hits max level or you run out of EXP.  Then check to determine if you need to reset `currentExp`

```
public void AddExp(int expToAdd)
{
    currentEXP += expToAdd;

    // while the player is not max level, level up to the equivalent level with 
    // all the exp gain up to that level
    while (playerLevel < maxLevel && currentEXP > expToNextLevel[playerLevel])
    {
        currentEXP -= expToNextLevel[playerLevel];
        playerLevel++;
    }

    // If the player has reached max level reset the current EXP
    if (playerLevel >= maxLevel) 
    {
        currentEXP = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem! Thank you so much!